# Cleaning up old versioned maven artifacts stored in aws s3 while using maven 3

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, maven-3

we are using aws s3 as the maven artifact repos and maven 3 pushes date time suffixed new artifacts for every maven deploy. we are planning to keep only two versions of the artifacts at s3.

Maven option `<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>` is removed in maven 3.

***Max unique snapshot*** option is one to automatically delete old versioned artifacts except the required one, but i dont think this will have effect on the artifacts stored in aws s3.

aws s3 has a life cycle management service for s3 objects to clean up old objects based on the object creation date (such as clean up a month old objects), but thats not suitable in my case as i have to always retain atleast two versions of an artifact despite how much old the artifact is.

anybody ran into this issue and solved it somehow?

Comment: For such purposes you should use a repository manager which has tasks to handle such things...like keeping only a specified number of SNAPSHOT versions etc.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on 'repository manager'? any link for the idea?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html